# Update stream on file change

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

With code below I read and print the content of file using Akka streams :

```
package playground

import java.nio.file.Paths
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Framing, Sink, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object Greeter extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("map-management-service")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("a.csv"))
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String)).runForeach(println)

}
```

My understanding of using Akka streams is that if the file changes/updates the processing code, in this case `println` is fired so each time the file is updated the entire file is re-read. But this is not occurring - the file is read once.

How should this be modified such that each time the file `a.csv` is updated the file is re-read and the `println` code is re-executed

Comment: Akka streams processes whatever is emitted from the source, so you need to check [its documentation](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FileIO%24.html#fromPath(f:java.nio.file.Path,chunkSize:Int):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.IOResult]]). From the description it is evident that the file is only read once (although it will emit multiple elements to the stream depending on the `chunkSize`)

Comment: Check out [Alpakka File Connectors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/file.html#listening-to-changes-in-a-directory) which seems to provide some polling `DirectoryChangesSource` that you could try to wire up further. Alternatively, you could implement your own custom source.

Comment: You would need create a Source based in something like tail, or using tools like logstash and read from a TCP port

Comment: You should probably create your own `Source`. I would look into the Java WatchService for providing the reactivity to file changes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpakka's [`DirectoryChangesSource`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/1.1.1/file.html#listening-to-changes-in-a-directory) could fit your use case. For example:

```
import akka.stream.alpakka.file.DirectoryChange
import akka.stream.alpakka.file.scaladsl.DirectoryChangesSource

implicit val system = ActorSystem("map-management-service")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val myFile = Paths.get("a.csv")
val changes = DirectoryChangesSource(Paths.get("."), pollInterval = 3.seconds, maxBufferSize = 1000)

changes
  .filter {
    case (path, dirChange) =>
      path.endsWith(myFile) && (dirChange == DirectoryChange.Creation || dirChange == DirectoryChange.Modification)
  }
  .flatMapConcat(_ => FileIO.fromPath(myFile).via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true)))
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .runForeach(println)
```

The above snippet prints the file contents when the file is created and whenever the file is modified, polling in three-second intervals.

Comment: This is the right approach but fails in practice with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The path 'a.csv' is not a directory`. You need to watch the directory instead and then filter on changes to the target file. I'll edit the response accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand on [Jeffrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58080689/396255) with a fully runnable [Ammonite script](https://ammonite.io/#ScalaScripts):

```
import $ivy.`com.lightbend.akka::akka-stream-alpakka-file:1.1.1`

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{ FileIO, Framing }
import akka.stream.alpakka.file.DirectoryChange
import akka.stream.alpakka.file.scaladsl.DirectoryChangesSource
import akka.util.ByteString
import java.nio.file.Paths
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("map-management-service")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val myFile = Paths.get("a.csv")
val changes = DirectoryChangesSource(Paths.get("."), pollInterval = 3.seconds, maxBufferSize = 1000)

changes
  .filter {
    case (path, dirChange) =>
      path.endsWith(myFile) && (dirChange == DirectoryChange.Creation || dirChange == DirectoryChange.Modification)
  }
  .flatMapConcat {
    case (path, _) => FileIO.fromPath(path).via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true))
  }
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .runForeach(println)
```

Please direct upvotes to his answer for the original idea.